When using extendBody + bottomNavigationBar ,The same content as listview and sliverList results in inconsistent scrolling behavior to the bottom
The same content causes inconsistent scrolling behavior to the bottom. I wish sliver could be like a listview, but now sliver scrolls a little longer and has a noticeable lag
ListView √
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
    statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
    systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.transparent,
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      extendBody: true,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: _buildBottom(),
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          const Column(
            children: [
              ListTile(title: Text('Item 1')),
              ListTile(title: Text('Item 2')),
              ListTile(title: Text('Item 3')),
              ListTile(title: Text('Item 8')),
              ListTile(title: Text('Item 8')),
              ListTile(title: Text('Item 8')),
            ],
          ),
          const TextField(),
          const Column(
            children: [
              ListTile(title: Text('Item 1')),
              ListTile(title: Text('Item 2')),
              ListTile(title: Text('Item 3')),
              ListTile(title: Text('Item 8')),
              ListTile(title: Text('Item 8')),
              ListTile(title: Text('Item 8')),
            ],
          ),
          Container(
            color: Colors.red,
            height: 140,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildBottom() {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.surface,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.outlineVariant.withOpacity(0.5), blurRadius: 12),
          ],
        ),
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 38, right: 38, bottom: 7),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 14, vertical: 4),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          children: [
            FilledButton(onPressed: () {}, child: const Text('add')),
            FilledButton(onPressed: () {}, child: const Text('add')),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


Sliver List   x

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
    statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
    systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.transparent,
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      extendBody: true,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: _buildBottom(),
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: [
          const SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                ListTile(title: Text('Item 1')),
                ListTile(title: Text('Item 2')),
                ListTile(title: Text('Item 3')),
                ListTile(title: Text('Item 8')),
                ListTile(title: Text('Item 8')),
                ListTile(title: Text('Item 8')),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          const SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: TextField(),
          ),
          const SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                ListTile(title: Text('Item 1')),
                ListTile(title: Text('Item 2')),
                ListTile(title: Text('Item 3')),
                ListTile(title: Text('Item 8')),
                ListTile(title: Text('Item 8')),
                ListTile(title: Text('Item 8')),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.red,
              height: 140,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildBottom() {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.surface,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.outlineVariant.withOpacity(0.5), blurRadius: 12),
          ],
        ),
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 38, right: 38, bottom: 7),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 14, vertical: 4),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          children: [
            FilledButton(onPressed: () {}, child: const Text('add')),
            FilledButton(onPressed: () {}, child: const Text('add')),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


Video
Listview
https://github.com/user-attachments/assets/3fdf2428-b192-47ea-a650-b417505af224
Sliver List
https://github.com/user-attachments/assets/2dbeb326-91e7-4de9-974c-eea58a3f95be
